# Padded structures using __attribute__(__packed__), is it really worth it?

Tags: c, gcc, struct

```
gcc (GCC) 4.7.0
c89
x86_64
```

Hello,

I am wondering is it worth it using using the `__attribute__ ((__packed__))` on structures. It seems to me that with it the structure will be smaller in size. Going by the test I have performed below. So using it would be an advantage in size.

A case for not using it, as it is not portable across other compilers. So for visual studio C++ this won't work. Plus other compilers as well.

Doesn't the compiler optimize the code? So really leaving it up to the compiler to decide what to do would be better for performance?

Would using the aligned attribute make any difference? `__attribute__((packed, aligned(4)))` When I added that it returned the size of 12.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct padded {
    int age;      /* 4                    */
    char initial; /* 1 + 3 padded bytes   */
    int weight;   /* 4     --> total = 12 */ 
};

struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) unpadded {
    int age;      /* 4                  */
    char initial; /* 1                  */
    int weight;   /* 4    --> total = 9 */
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct padded padded_test;
    struct unpadded unpadded_test;

    printf("Padded   [ %ld ]\n", sizeof(struct padded));
    printf("Unpadded [ %ld ]\n", sizeof(struct unpadded));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unaligned memory access is slower

Comment: For your example structure, packing it *and* 4-aligning it is especially non-worthwhile. You don't save any space, you just de-align the `weight` field. The only reason to do it is to match some pre-existing layout defined that way (and even that assumes you know that the object representation of `int` on your platform is correct for the `age` field, etc).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unaligned memory access can be horrendously slow on some architectures (e.g. ia64, sparc64).  `__attribute__((__packed__))` is principally intended for use where you're sending data over the wire and want to be sure of the layout; it's not worth trying to use it to save space in memory.

If you *are* considering using `__attribute__((__packed__))` for wire transmission, think again; it doesn't handle endianness, and it's non-standard.  Writing marshalling code yourself is safer, and using a library (e.g. Protocol Buffers) is smarter.

Comment: You can *just about* use `__packed__` for transmission of an already-defined format (such as a public protocol), dealing with endianness by the likes of `htonl`. But even then it's barely worth it, you're about as well off coding the sizes and offsets of the fields explicitly as you are writing a struct that you reckon matches the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Another use of `__attribute__((packed))` is for accessing memory mapped controllers.  As other people have suggested, not really useful except for very specific things. Unaligned access is bad and on some architectures it generates exceptions.